# SVG SMIL animation not behaving as expected

Tags: svg, smil

Does anyone know what's wrong with the center of this SVG SMIL pie animation?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/fj7Xc/

It appears like this:

[image]

Whereas it should be appearing like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="svg_wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 600 425">
        <path d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,150 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,-150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000">
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks fine in Chrome, but looks off in firefox. In that case, firefox bug.

Comment: Hi! Actually I took that screenshot in Chrome. Could you take a quick screenshot yourself?

Comment: Ah my mistake - it's there in my Chrome too although not that noticeable. In Firefox, it's very noticeable. A bigger problem is that the resulting shape isn't round in Chrome, it's a little squarish

Answer (score 2):

In both browsers, I think the problem comes down to the fact that you are hacking a stroke animation technique to try to get the fill animated the way you want.

That's a problem, because the browsers aren't calculating either the outer circle or the inner pivot point exactly -- they are calculating the official circle, halfway in between, rounding it off according to the resolution of your screen, and then drawing the stroke on either side.  Because the stroke is so large, the little rounding effects on the edge of the circle get exacerbated.

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for you except to use Javascript to calculate out the actual path for a pie-piece at each frame of the animation.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this was the former solution, I'm glad you had the insight to suggest it be used: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/gFnw9/19/ -- unfortunately it is way more complex than a simple SMIL and I truly hope there's a way around it.

Comment: A buddy and I just filed http://crbug.com/395474 -- do you think the two are related somehow?

Comment: I assume so, though the example you have in the bug report is extreme enough I'm not sure if rounding errors can justify it!